# How to go from printing [1, 2, 3] to printing 1, 2, 3 in a text file Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using the following loop to iterate over a numpy array and print into a separate text file.

```
c= np.array([1, 2, 3])
nc = c.astype(np.int)
for x in nc:
    print >> thing_here, x
```

yet when I open the thing_here text file it prints my array as `[1, 2, 3]` rather than `1, 2, 3`

How can I get rid of the [ ]'s?

Comment: `print >> thing_here, repr(x)[1:-1]`.

Comment: `', '.join(map(str, x))`, but may-be it is better to use `csv.writer` directly?

Comment: @ChristianDean That causes it to print as   rray([1, 2, 3])

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem (click the tick mark next to the answer)

Answer (score 2):

the `join` command will do this:

```
c = np.array([1,2,3])
c_joined = ' '.join(map(str,c))
```

If the array is already a list of strings, you can ignore the `map()` command and just use:

```
c = np.array([1,2,3])
c_joined = ' '.join(c)
```

Then do the print to file commands using this joined string. As a further note, `np.savetxt()` is a useful command